NHS MESH and FHIR Unreadable message received
I'm trying to send a FHIR document through the NHS MESH system, but it the messages is not being received.
I'm using the SDK for creating a package. I've created a package that contains  Composition, Patient, Practitioner and Organisation (not yet added a PDF. Want the get the basic message sorted). There is no errors on the FHIR validation site (https://validator.fhir.org/).
Sent the message on MESH to the validation mailbox, but still getting an Unreadable message received.
The FHIR document sent can here FHIR Document.

The Bundle might be a valid FHIR Bundle, but it is actually not valid against the FHIR profile you claim to use for it (https://fhir.nhs.uk/STU3/StructureDefinition/ITK-Document-Bundle-1).
As you can see from the url, the profile uses FHIR STU3. In your Bundle, you have a timestamp field filled in, but this is a field that was only introduced in FHIR R4. Easily corrected by removing it.
But then, when the corrected Bundle is validated against the profile, you will get at least 7 errors showing that you do not follow the rules for the document as specified in the profile. To check this I've input your Bundle into the Simplifier validator (https://simplifier.net/validate, note that an account is needed for this) and set the scope for validation to NHSDigital.FHIR.STU3 1.3.0 (https://simplifier.net/validate?scope=NHSDigital.FHIR.STU3@1.3.0), which is the package containing the profile definitions mentioned in your Bundle.

Thanks for you're comment, I will look at this.  The main problem they state, I'm missing a ITK Wrapper.  Are you able to help with what and how I can sent my document using the ITK Wrapper?

No, sorry, I do not know their communication protocols, and was just looking at this from a FHIR perspective in case that was the problem. The NHS must have some support available for that, maybe look at the ITK page: https://digital.nhs.uk/services/interoperability-toolkit?
